# Delphi application hanging up

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

This Delphi 2006 application has run successfully for several years. I have narrowed it hanging up to some point before it gets to the "initialize" in the DPR file so its hanging up before any written code gets executed. I press the "Run" icon and it never displays anything else, just stops running. Not much info to give, any ideas?

Comment: Actually, there's a lot of information for you to give.  For starters, when you say its run successfully, do you mean its compiled and run successfully, or that the same exact .exe file has been used for years and that now suddenly wont run.  There's a big, big difference between the two.  Basically, you need to flesh out your question more because we're not mind readers.

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of things happening before the Initialize line runs.  Most obviously, the **initialization** sections of all your units are running.  My psychic debugging senses say you ought to check there.  Build with `Use Debug DCUs` off (yes, *off*, not on; it helps a lot on this exercise,) run by hitting F7 instead of F9, and use F7 repeatedly to step through your chain of initializations.  Somewhere along the line you'll probably find whatever's making your program hang.

Comment: +1 for My psychic debugging senses... I used to say something like that in Spanish... :D